# Can you tell how much money a user sent and sender/reciever when it comes to Zero Knowledge Proofs?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, zero-knowledge

As I understand Zero-Knowledge Proofs:

- You can tell someone sent a certain amount of money
- You can tell someone received a certain amount of money
- But you can't cryptographically tie the two together.

Or is even that information hidden?

Comment: Zero-knowledge proofs are a cryptographic primitive, but you are asking about a particular use case. For this question to make sense, you'd need to specify what product you are talking about (zksync? Aztec? loopring?)

Comment: I'm particularly curious about Ethereum but curious in general. An answer that listed various Zero-Knowledge Proofs and which of these three could and couldn't be tracked for each one would probably be awarded the solution.

Comment: Properly implemented you can hide amounts and participants.